# Difference between OOP and ORM

Tags: oop, orm

I'm new to programming and I've been wondering what is the difference between ORM - Object–relational mapping and OOP - Object-oriented programming

Comment: ORM and OOP are two orthogonal concepts, so there's really no similarity at all between them. If you look up both concepts on e.g. Wikipedia, what does that tell you?

Comment: I agree with @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: This is what I know: ORM - mapping of objects to databases (imagine a mapping of class in your program to a table in database). OOP - it's a programming methodology.

Comment: I now understand the whole concept of both terms. Just had to go slowly through them. Thank you !